# what should I publish while edit in view page without edit code in asp.net core

Tags: asp.net

I'm using aspNet core

if I want to republish my project using ftp account. what should I publish file(s) if I only edit view page (not code behind). and what should I publish file(s) if I update my code behind!?

note: old version asp.net (web form) I was publish aspx (design) but I there an edit in code behind I was publish (dll) for project.

please, guide me ...

Answer (score 0):

Views are compiled in asp.net core 2.0 onwards and it produces [your_application_name].Views.dll.
So you need to ftp that.

And other application codes produces dlls based on your project structure project.
Like your presentation layer will produce one dll, your business layer project will produce another dll and your data access layer will produce another dll.

Like you can see in this image, when my project structure is like the below; what are the different files appear when we publish the project.
[image]

[image]

Comment: i'm using aspNet Core 3
should I use specific files or specific method to publish my files?

Comment: published file shown like this: 
https://ibb.co/CzBCN4j

Comment: That's the output in bin folder it looks. How are you publishing ?